# What could be a reason for data to be missing from a Cassandra table?

Tags: cassandra, missing-data

When I query a table in my Cassandra database (in an EC2 instance), data before 2022-04-15 are not showing. The table had data from November of 2021.

I am new to Cassandra. What could have happened? Last week I exported data to CSV in addition to my usual work.

Comment: A friendly reminder that Stack Overflow is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems. For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. If you post it there, I'd be happy to help. Cheers!

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/314893/lot-of-rows-suddenly-not-showing-in-the-cassandra-database